# Menu Item in Action bar hide in small screen in android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menu, android-actionbar

I am using an actionbar with actionbar tab in an app. i have menu item and three tab with home icon in actionbar.

**BUT** When i run this app on emulator if menu item has property showAsAction with value "ifroom" then some of them are appear because of no more room

but the menu icon at the right upper corner is missing everytime i run this app.

Here is the image what is come in emulator :

[image: Actionbar without menu list icon]

and image below what i need :

[image: Output i need with menu item]

here is my code for menu.xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_add" android:title="Add" android:icon="@drawable/icon" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_DashBoard" android:title="DashBoard" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_Master_Entry" android:title="Master Entry" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_Product_Section" android:title="Product Section" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_Retailers_Orders" android:title="Retailers Orders" />

        


<item android:id="@+id/action_search" android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:title="Search" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" android:layout_gravity="left"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_calender" android:title="Calender"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" android:icon="@drawable/calender" android:layout_gravity="left" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_message" android:title="Message"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" android:icon="@drawable/messageicon" android:layout_gravity="left"/>
```

Please help .. why it is come and what is the solution of this problem?

THANKS in advance. I only want that this menu dropdown at the last in actionbar should be shown in each screen size but it disappear in phone and shown on tab(10.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can change `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to `android:showAsAction="always"`but this is not recommended.

If there is not enough room this items are added to more option at the end of the action bar where thr title of this item is shown in a drop-down (kind of) list.

Comment: ya i know but i missed that drop down list either i remove this 3 (ifroom attribute item ). I just want that this drop down list should be placed at the last of actionbar but it doesnot show any menu drop down??

Comment: The list icon i want is drop down menu . which is disappear . i only need that it should be shown on action bar